# I need to show funds according to the category selected in point 1

Tags: javascript, python, django

django application, I need to take categories from the database (step 1) and based on them (step 3) show the funds that belong to these categories, how can this be done in js? Thank you

```
models.py
TYPE = (
    (1, 'fundacja'),
    (2, 'organizacja pozarządowa'),
    (3, 'zbiórka lokalna'),
)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE, default=1)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def type_name(self):
        return TYPE[self.type - 1][1]

class Donation(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    pick_up_date = models.DateField()
    pick_up_time = models.TimeField()
    pick_up_comment = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    is_taken = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    taken_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)    

views.py
class DonationView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        all_category = Category.objects.all()
        all_institution = Institution.objects.all()
        context = {
            'all_category': all_category,
            'all_institution': all_institution,
        }
        return render(request, 'form.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            institution_name = request.POST.get('organization')
            institution = Institution.objects.get(name=institution_name)
            categories_names = request.POST.getlist('categories')
            categories_ids = []
            for category_name in categories_names:
                category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)
                categories_ids.append(category.id)
            quantity = request.POST.get('bags')
            address = request.POST.get('address')
            phone_number = request.POST.get('phone')
            city = request.POST.get('city')
            zip_code = request.POST.get('postcode')
            pick_up_date_str = request.POST.get('data')
            pick_up_date = datetime.strptime(pick_up_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            pick_up_time = request.POST.get('time')
            pick_up_comment = request.POST.get('more_info')
            new_donation = Donation.objects.create(quantity=quantity, institution=institution,
                                                   address=address, phone_number=phone_number, city=city,
                                                   zip_code=zip_code, pick_up_date=pick_up_date,
                                                   pick_up_time=pick_up_time,
                                                   pick_up_comment=pick_up_comment, user=request.user)

            new_donation.save()
            return render(request, 'form-confirmation.html')
        except Exception:
            return HttpResponseServerError('Error')


 js:
let selectedCategories = [];
let selectedInstitution = [];
let numberOfBags = 0;
let selectedAddress = {};
let selectedDate = {};

document.querySelector('div[data-step="1"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectedCategories = [];

    const checkedCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="categories"]:checked');

    checkedCheckboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        selectedCategories.push(checkbox.value);
    });

    filterOrganizationsByCategory(selectedCategories);
        updateSummaryText();
});

document.querySelector('div[data-step="2"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[name="bags"]');
    numberOfBags = parseInt(inputElement.value);
console.log(selectedCategories)
    updateSummaryText();
});

document.querySelector('div[data-step="3"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectedInstitution = [];

    const checkedInstitutions = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="organization"]:checked');

    checkedInstitutions.forEach((checkbox) => {
        selectedInstitution.push(checkbox.value);
    });

    updateSummaryText();
});

}

HTML

      <form action="" method="post" >
        {%  csrf_token %}
          <!-- STEP 1: class .active is switching steps -->
          <div data-step="1" class="active">
            <h3>Zaznacz co chcesz oddać:</h3>
                  {%  for category in all_category %}
            <div class="form-group form-group--checkbox">
              <label>

                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="categories"
                  value="{{ category.name }}"
                />
                <span class="checkbox"></span>
                                  <span class="description"
                  >{{ category }}</span>

              </label>
            </div>
                  {% endfor %}

            <div class="form-group form-group--buttons">
              <button type="button" class="btn next-step">Dalej</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="step1_data" value="{{ data_from_step1 }}" />

          <!-- STEP 2 -->
          <div data-step="2">
            <h3>Podaj liczbę 60l worków, w które spakowałeś/aś rzeczy:</h3>

            <div class="form-group form-group--inline">
              <label>
                Liczba 60l worków:
                <input type="number" name="bags" step="1" min="1" />
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group form-group--buttons">
              <button type="button" class="btn prev-step">Wstecz</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn next-step">Dalej</button>
            </div>
          </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="step2_data" value="{{ data_from_step2 }}" />



          <!-- STEP 3 -->
          <div data-step="3" id="step-3">
            <h3>Wybierz organizacje, której chcesz pomóc:</h3>
        {% for institution in all_institution %}
            <div class="form-group form-group--checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="organization" value="{{ institution.name }}" data-category="">
                <span class="checkbox radio"></span>
                <span class="description">
                  <div class="title">{{ institution.name }}</div>
                  <div class="subtitle">
                    {{ institution.description }}
                  </div>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
              {% endfor %}
```

django application, I need to take categories from the database (step 1) and based on them (step 3) show the funds that belong to these categories, how can this be done in js? Thank you

Comment: Do you just need to practise with JavaScript? Or you just don't want Django to do the filtering? Because you can achieve what you need without a single line of JavaScript.

Comment: This is a class assignment and I need to do it in JavaScript